# How i can reduce block code if else

Tags: javascript, dom, scroll

Have a page with height 4600px and have if else statement in scroll elements
smoothly moving right or left.But this if else block very big.I need to reduce it.Please help anyone

```
var withAp = document.querySelector('.withAp');

window.onscroll = function() {

  var scrolled = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;

  if (scrolled < 100 ) {
    withAp.style.marginRight = '0';
    withAp.style.opacity = '0.1';
  }
  if (scrolled > 100  ) { 
    withAp.style.marginRight = '30px';
    withAp.style.opacity = '0.2';
  }
  if (scrolled > 200) { 
    withAp.style.marginRight = '50px';
    withAp.style.opacity = '0.2';
  }
};
```

Comment: Is this a snippet of something much longer? At the moment it doesn't seem to be "very big".

Comment: @ Phylogenesis look i cant just paste all code

Comment: That also isn't an "if else block" as there is no else.  You will run into problems if the `scrolled` is greater than 200px, you will hit both statements.

Comment: @DuuudeXX8 That's fine but a `// ...` before the closing brace would give an indication that this is a snippet, rather than the entire thing

Comment: As an example, I came up with [this](https://jsfiddle.net/f6e2svz9/1/). This assumes that the first step is 30 pixels, then each further step is an additional 20 pixels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var withAp = document.querySelector('.withAp');

window.onscroll = function() {

var scrolled = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;

  if (scrolled > 100  ) { 
    withAp.style.marginRight = '30px';
    withAp.style.opacity = '0.2';
  } else {
      withAp.style.marginRight = '0';
      withAp.style.opacity = '0.1';  
  }
  if (scrolled > 200) { 
    withAp.style.marginRight = '50px';
    withAp.style.opacity = '0.2';
  }
};
```

You can do this without checking is scrolled less then 100 because if it's not greater it is less or equal so that can go in else block.

Comment: I didnt say you dont need check sroll, I said `if (scrolled < 100 ) {}` you dont need this condition, code from this block can be inside `else {}` look at my code in answer